# Colour code circle objects based on number of overlapping regions

Tags: matlab

How to create a plot with overlapping circles in which overlapping regions are color-coded according to the number of circles that overlap there?

```
clear; 
noOfNodes = 200; 

x = rand(1,1000 )*1000; 
y = rand(1,1000 )*1000; 

R = 8; 

netXloc = x; 
netYloc = y; 

grid on
set(gca, 'GridLineStyle', '-');
grid(gca,'minor')

hold on

scatter ( x, y, 'R.'); 
axis square 
hold on

axis ( [ 0.0, 1000.0, 0.0, 1000.0 ] ) 
title ( 'WSN coverage' ); 

hold off

for i = 1:1000 

        ctr = [x(i) y(i)]-R; 
        diameter = 2*R; 
        h = rectangle('Position',[ctr,diameter,diameter],'FaceColor',[0.5 0.5 0.5],'Curvature',[1,1],'LineWidth',.5,'LineStyle','-'); 
     alpha .6;
        end;
```

Comment: What was the question again? What is this code supposed to do that it doesn't? Please try to ask a question the same way as if you were to ask a colleague: Tell us what you want to do, what you tried that didn't work, and where you need help.

Comment: Who disallowed edits I made to this question? I made *effort* to salvage question in the intention to answer it (for my own satisfaction at least) and someone just threw away that only to be able to down-vote question... How useful is that? Can reviewer who done that explain why he did it?

Comment: @zplesivcak It takes a few people to reject an edit. I don't know what that first edit contained, but you shouldn't just delete all code. I added your improvements of the other edit. +1 for your answer.

Comment: @kapep Thank you for your response. I've reviewed the code from the answer and have concluded that it is irrelevant. Anyhow, it could stay, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it:

```
% size of image
sz = [800 800];

% generate coordinates
y = 1:sz(1);
x = 1:sz(2);
[xx yy] = meshgrid(x,y);

% draw circles
ci1 = (xx-300).^2 + (yy-400).^2 <= 200^2;
ci2 = (xx-500).^2 + (yy-400).^2 <= 200^2;
ci3 = (xx-400).^2 + (yy-300).^2 <= 200^2;
ci4 = (xx-400).^2 + (yy-500).^2 <= 200^2;

% draw image containing circles
figure; imagesc(ci1 + ci2 + ci3 + ci4);
```

Here's the result:

[image]